# How to extract characters between two numbers?

Tags: r, regex

I have a string where I want to extract all the characters between two numbers (all characters without scpaces at start and end). In fact the situation is a bit trickier because sometimes there are numbers in the string and sometimes not. Let the string be:

```
my_string <- c("12 aöc-ABC 3 a", "43XY/zz23ab", "acs", "23 as c", "f~ds22 d", "1 3")
```

In this case my expected output is

```
expected_string <- c("aöc-ABC", "XY/zz", "acs", "as c", "f~ds", NA)
```

As you can see sometimes there are numbers before and after the relevant part (1st and 2nd entry), sometimes there are no numbers at all (3rd entry), numbers only before or only after the interesting part (4th and 5th entries) or just numbers with no part I am interested in (last entry).

I tried

```
gsub("^\\d*\\s*([^[:digit:]])+\\d*.*", "\\1", my_string)
```

but I don't get the desired output and do not know why. I really want to use gsub() in order to understand regex better. Meaning that I want to avoid using strsplit (which may be easier here..). Hope there are regex masters that can help me with that one!

Comment: From these example data, if there is only one number, do you want everything after that number? Your 4th position in your `my_string` would suggest this, just wanted to confirm

Comment: You just have a typo, you need the "not digit" `+` quantifier **inside** the capture group `()`, not outside the capture group. Change `)+` to `+)` so the pattern is: `"^\\d*\\s*([^[:digit:]]+)\\d*.*"` (Though that will give you a `" "` not a `NA` for the last example.)

Comment: @jpsmith Yes, all after that number

Comment: I highly recommend https://regex101.com/ for debugging regex - I put in your pattern and your test cases and it helped me find the issue pretty quickly :)

Comment: @GregorThomas May I ask you how to use the site? I copied `^\\d*\\s*([^[:digit:]])+\\d*.*` as regular expression and `c("12 aöc-ABC 3 a", "43XY/zz23ab", "acs", "23 as c", "f~ds22 d", "1 3")` as test string but wont work. (I know only R language, maybe thats why I dont get it)

Comment: You could also consider using `\D` in your capture group. This is the negation of `\d`, which means anything not a digit.

Comment: @IngoPingo double backslashes should be changed to one, e.g. ```\\d``` becomes ```\d```. And groups are defined as `$1` instead of ```\\1``` in substitution.

Comment: @GregorThomas that pattern does not work for ```23 as c```. https://regex101.com/r/lYLdSR/1

Comment: @M-- interesting... I see that it doesn't work for `"23 as c"` but I am stumped as to *why*.

Comment: @M-- it seems to be something to do with the previous line... in R `"23 as c"` returns `"as c"` as expected, and if you type (not copy/paste) "23 as c" into a new line on Regex101 it also works... seems like a bug or perhaps just a confusing option on Regex101.

Answer (score 2):

Split on spaces, digits and spaces and then remove empty strings and take first component (which will be NA if there are none).

```
sapply(strsplit(my_string, " *\\d+ *"), function(x) x[x != ""][1])
## [1] "aöc-ABC" "XY/zz"   "acs"     "as c"    "f~ds"    NA
```

Comment: As expected using strsplit is easier. The question was more about arriving there by understanding regex. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `stringr` option

```
library(stringr)

str_match(my_string, "\\d?\\s?(\\D+)\\s?\\d?")[,2] |>
  dplyr::na_if(" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

A way might be to do the job with two `sub` removing form begin and from end. And if needed `replace` `""` with `NA` afterwards.

```
s <- sub(" *\\d+.*$", "", sub("^\\d+ *", "", my_string))
s
#[1] "aöc-ABC" "XY/zz"   "acs"     "as c"    "f~ds"    ""

replace(s, s == "", NA)
#[1] "aöc-ABC" "XY/zz"   "acs"     "as c"    "f~ds"    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
data.frame(my_string) %>%
  # mutate `my_string` *if* the values contain a digit...
  mutate(my_string = ifelse(str_detect(my_string, "\\d"),
                     # ...by extracting either anything that is *not* a digit... 
                     # ...if wrapped into digits OR without that condition:
                     trimws(str_extract(my_string, "(?<=\\d{1,10})\\D+(?=\\d+)|\\D+")),
                     # else use values as are:
                     my_string),
           # convert empty values to `NA`:               
           my_string = na_if(my_string, "")
           )
  my_string
1   aöc-ABC
2     XY/zz
3       acs
4      as c
5      f~ds
6      <NA>
```

Answer (score 0):

As @GregorThomas pointed out in the comments I was very close to the solution! So for the sake of completeness here the corrected code from my question

```
gsub("^\\d*\\s*([^[:digit:]]+)\\d*.*", "\\1", my_string)
```

The only difference to the code in question is that the plus is inside the group, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

```
L = ("12 aöc-ABC 3 a", "43XY/zz23ab", "acs", "23 as c", "f~ds22 d", "1 3")
T=[]
for i in L:
    S = list(i)
    L1=""
    for i in S:
        if "0" <= i <="9":
            pass
        else:
            L1+=i
    T.append(L1.strip())
print(tuple(T))

# O/P :- ('aöc-ABC  a', 'XY/zzab', 'acs', 'as c', 'f~ds d', '')
```

Comment: This isn't R code and does not accurately answer the question.